# String concatenation showing unexpected behavior

Tags: java

Bellow is snippet of my code. I just want to know why if condition is not being executed even if variable "ans" has value 2020.

```
private static void solve() throws Exception {
    
        String str="20";
        String str1="20";
        String ans=str+str1;
    
        if(ans=="2020")
         System.out.println("matched");
       else System.out.println("Not matched");

        System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Comment: Use `equals` instead of `==` for `String` compares

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: yes actually equal method shows correct behavior but why in java == operator not showing correct behavior like c & c++

Answer (score 1):

```
ans.equals("2020")
```

this should work.

Comment: "2020".equals(ans) - this way there won't be NPE

Comment: Thanks for replying but could you please explain why == is not working like c++

Comment: @HrishiBargal because A==B means A and B are the same object in java. ans = "20" + "20" create a new String object, the constant String "2020" is a different Object.